# Issues minifying CSS/JS with jekyll-assets

Tags: javascript, css, jekyll, minify

I'm having issues getting my asset pipeline to cooperate with minifying the CSS and JS. The Jekyll sites that I'm working with use SCSS and CSS. I'm wondering what steps need to be done in order to properly implement `jekyll-assets` to minify the SCSS, CSS, and JS?

I've tried adding the following to my `_config.yml` file:

```
plugins: [bourbon, neat, jekyll-sitemap, jekyll-assets]
sass:
  style: compressed
assets:
  sources:
    - assets/css
    - assets/images
    - assets/js
  compress:
    css:  true
    js:   uglifier
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'jekyll', '3.5.0'
gem 'bourbon', '4.3.4'
gem 'neat', '1.8.0'
gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
gem 'sprockets', '3.7.2'
gem 'jekyll-assets'
gem 'uglifier'
```

In the html templates, I've used tags like `{% css normalize %}`, however I can't get anything to minify with the `jekyll-assets` plugin (only the built-in Jekyll sass compression works). I'm pretty new to Jekyll, and I've been sifting through the documentation (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jekyll-assets/) and can't seem to figure this out. Any insight would be appreciated, since I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Did you solve this? Do you have a github repo where I can check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are in "production" mode when doing `jekyll build`.  A number of configurations in `_config.yml` for `jekyll-assets` change when you run build with/without `JEKYLL_ENV=production` set.

**By default, `jekyll-asset` compression is false.**

See configuration documentation of `jekyll-assets` here:
https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-assets#configuration

> *Setting a value makes it explicit, and shared across both **production**, and **development***.

```
assets:
  source_maps: true # false on JEKYLL_ENV=production
  destination: "/assets"
  compression: false # true on JEKYLL_ENV=production
  ...
```

---

Try running `JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build`